# Ratio between two datasets with conditions in R

Tags: r

I have two data sets. One dataset is dye and it has two columns time and dye and another dataset is sed. Sed dataset has also time and sed. Then I want to find the new variable new from the ratio of the sed to dye. I want to find the ratio such that if either dye or sed is zero then new would be zero else calculate new as sed /dye.

The code I have worked so far is as follows:

```
dyei94j66 <- read.table("i94 j66 dye time series.Dat",header=T,sep="\t")
names(dyei94j66) <- c("Time","Dye")
head(dyei94j66)
sedi94j66 <- read.table("i94 j66 sediment time series.Dat", header=T,sep="\t")
names(sedi94j66) <- c("Time","Sed")
head(sedi94j66)
newi94j66 <- data.frame(sedi94j66$Sed / dyei94j66$Dye)
head(newi94j66)
# Merge two datasets
totaldata <- merge(dyei94j66,sedi94j66, all=TRUE)
```

I didn't know how to use the condition to calculate the ratio. May be I need to create a function I am not sure. Right now, when either dye or sed is zero then the value calculated by R is NaN. So, I want to change that NaN to zero while calculating the ratio.

I hope I explained what I am looking for. Thanks.

The data for i94 j66 sediment time series can be found on https://www.dropbox.com/s/1cbo8wul9nb8zeh/i94%20j66%20sediment%20time%20series.Dat 
The data for i94 j66 dey time series can be found on https://www.dropbox.com/s/sqm8rip2xjh3tiu/i94%20j66%20dye%20time%20series.Dat

Comment: You could use `is.finite` to replace with 0 afterwards. Your example code appears merge the two data sets by time, after you have performed calculations on the unmerged data. This would appear to be shortsighted.

Comment: @mnel thank you for your reply. But can you show example on how to use is.finite . When I tried to use that it would give me true or false. Regarding the merge I was just practicing merging. Eventually, I merged data first and then calculated the ratio. The code I used is                                              datai94j66$Age <- is.finite(with(datai94j66,Sed/Dye))                where datai94j66 is merged data set of dye and sed.

Comment: I was implying something like `datai94j66$Age <- with(datai94j66,Sed/Dye); datai94j66$Age <- replace(datai94j66$Age,!is.finite(datai94j66$Age)),0)`

Comment: Thank you so much. datai94j66$Age <- replace(datai94j66$Age,!is.finite(datai94j66$Age),0) There was one extra parenthesis which confused me initially. Works like a charm. Thanks.